# No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi

Tags: flutter

I was working on a **Flutter** project and everything was working fine until I updated My **Android Studio** and some of the **SDK tools**. Then when I was trying to run my project, I was getting the Error below:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

*   What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi

*   Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

*   Get more help at [https://help.gradle.org](https://help.gradle.org)

BUILD FAILED in 1m 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

So what have gone wrong? What should I do?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well I solved the issue in 2 different ways:

**A.** I **downgraded** my **NDK** from version `23.0.7123448` to `22.0.7026061` by simple steps below:

1.Open **SDK Manager** from tool bar of android studio or from settings menu (File --> Settings --> Appearance and Behavior --> System Settings --> Android SDK).

[image]

2. Select the **SDK Tools** tab and from the Bottom Right of the window check the **Show package details**. Then simply **uncheck** any version you want to delete and select **Apply**.

[image]

(For me removing version `23.0.7123448` and get to `22.0.7026061` solved the problem. But if you are still having the Error above try to **lower** the **NDK** version. **The most stable** NDK version is `20.1.5948944`)

3. If you have done all the steps before, you will see the following window popping up. Hit OK and you are all set.

[image]

**B.** This approach might look simple but yet it does the trick. Simply create a new Flutter project and get all you work (lib folder, assets, etc) to the new project.

Comment: It's weird, none of the grade nor ndk solutions worked for me.

Comment: @eigenfield Did you updated Flutter?

Comment: I'm not using Flutter. I'm following this https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-setup and it failed due to `arm-linux-androideabi` error message. I tried all that can be tried, read the github chats, change gradle this that, add all NDK, `local.properties` etc I even filtered out `arm` builds to stick to `x86` builds and i'm still getting this error. All other `RN` documentation works fine so I guess I'll just avoid this particular one that failed.

Answer (score 46):

The main reason is that NDK 23 has different toolchain than the previous versions of NDK (22-), so the old version of AGP (Android Gradle Plugin) has not idea where to find the executables for different ABIs.

For me, simply update the AGP version in the `build.gradle` in your Android project root to 4.0+, such as

```
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
        ...
```

This will resolve the problem.

**Note**: You will need to set the environment variable `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` to your NDK 22- location, even Google's document does not require that or says it is deprecated.

If you want to stick to the current version of AGP, there is another work around, simply add this

```
android {
    android.ndkVersion "21.4.7075529" // (or whichever NDK 22- version you have installed)
    ...
```

to your module's `build.gradle` (not the `build.gradle` of your project)

Some other ways to work around this can be found here, [Configure the NDK for the Android Gradle plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-agp-ndk)

Comment: Nope, didn't work for me.

Answer (score 13):

---

#### Environment

OS : Big Sur 11.1 
npm 7.24.0 
 
node v14.15.5 
 
react-native-cli: 2.0.1 
react-native: 0.63.4

---

#### Command

`react-native run-android`

---

#### Error

*What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi

---

#### Fix

Checking Android SDK Tools, NDK (side-by-side):
In the android toolbar go to: 
Tools >> SDK Manager 
![Tools-SDK][1]

Then in the popup aside navigation go to: 
Appearance & Behavior >> System Settings >> Android SDK 
[image: Android SDK]￼

Click “SDK Tools”
[image: SDK Tools]

Check the box next to show package details
[image: Show Package Details]￼

**Solution:**
Downgrade 
[image: Downgrade]

---

#### References

Idea for downgrade: [Taba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8346770/taba)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66922162/no-toolchains-found-in-the-ndk-toolchains-folder-for-abi-with-prefix-arm-linux)

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me
I updated AGP to 4.1+ in my Android Project root build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"
    ...
```

AGP 4.1+ supports only gradle version gradle-6.5 above
so I updated the **distributionUrl** in gradle-wrapper.properties file located in gradle/wrapper folder

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Get more info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-agp-ndk)

Comment: This worked with a gradlew clean.Thank you

Answer (score 4):

what worked for me was

- I change my Gradle dependencies from 3.5.1 to 4.0.1

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    }
```

which is under build.gradle

- The minimum Gradle support for Gradle dependencies(gradle:4.0.1) is gradle-6.1.1

if your gradle version for the project is below that you will have to change it by downloading a higher version or if you have it and you're using a wrapper, you will have to change the distribution to the one higher or same as the 6.1.1 version.
which is under >gradle >wrapple >gradle-wrapple.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

- You might most likely need to add to your NDK
  for Gradle-6.7 the supported NDK is NDK(side by side) version 21.0.6113669
  which is under >tools >sdk manager(android SDK) >sdk tools >ndk side by side
  click show package details click and download the appropriate one for you

Answer (score 2):

I've cleared all the SDK folders in
`c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\`

Answer (score 0):

Recent **AppCenter android dependencies changes** caused my android builds to fail with this error:

`No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi`

Our solution was to upgrade the gradle version from `3.5.4`  to `4.0.1` in the root build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional answer for @gwang and @TillyJonesy:

When running Gradle command with `--info`(AGP 3.5.4 for me), you will see that when no NDK version was given, AGP will try to use the highest NDK version.

[image]

[image]

And from the docs of Android NDK guidance, AGP <= 3.5 has no default NDK version.

See: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#default-ndk-per-agp

Answer (score 0):

Solution for native android developers

Go to File->Settings->Appearance & Behaviour->System Settings->Android SDK-> then select SDK Tools and check 'Show Package Details' from bottom.

in Dropdown of NDK(Side by Side) ,check 22.1.7171670 and uncheck remaining then apply and click ok.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in my case, my react native version is `0.62.2` and the gradle version is `6.1.1` so I update the gradle version

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

after that update (under android/build.gradle)

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2")
```

to

```
  classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3')
```

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of this error by unchecking all NDK versions from Android Studio SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I refere this github issue page and my problem solve
[doc](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob/issues/213)