# Android Studio: No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, dart

When i make flutter run, this message appear in my terminal:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66922162/no-toolchains-found-in-the-ndk-toolchains-folder-for-abi-with-prefix-arm-linux