# Error while running the app (No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi )

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

This is the error I got,

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix:
> arm-linux-androideabi

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi
```

flutter doctor summary is below,

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1826], locale en-GB)      
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.69.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

this is pretty old project sill didn't migrated.

Image of Android studio [NDK version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQtrB.png)

Comment: did you fix this error?

Comment: I have found the solution here by updating the classpath: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66922162/no-toolchains-found-in-the-ndk-toolchains-folder-for-abi-with-prefix-arm-linux

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Open sdk manager in android studio and check